# How to check when polling stopped

Tags: java

I have a message stream, where messages comes which I need to process and then store them in database. In Java, I've written polling code which polls stream and consumes messages every 20 seconds.

This is done inside an infinite for-loop, like below:

```
for (;;) {
    try{
        //1. Logic for polling.
        //2. Logic for processing the message.
        //3. Logic for storing the message in database.
        Thread.sleep(20000 - <time taken for above 3 steps >); 
    } catch(Exception E){
        //4. Exception handling.
    }
}
```

This logic runs as expected and the stream is polled, but once in a while it hits an exception or something goes wrong and polling stops.

I want to have a mechanism, that as soon as polling stopped, let's say this `for` loop is not running for 60 seconds, I should receive a mail or ping.

How can I invoke a method if this for loop is not running for 60 seconds?

I am thinking like, each for-loop execution will ping a heartbeat, and when that heartbeat pinging not received from for-loop then a mail sending is invoked.

Comment: What prevents the loop from running? That determines a strategy for detecting that it's not.  You don't want to add a detection mehanism that's more likely to get stuck than the loop is...

Comment: I already have several catch logics and handling as per the exceptions. Still once in couple of days, polling stops with new error. I want to know when polling stopped, so that I quickly read the logs for errors, otherwise the error reasons are lost in tonnes of cloud logs.

Comment: Are you able to provide the rest of the logic inside the for loop try/catch block?

Comment: Why not alert on an unhandled exception?

Answer (score 3):

There are two different reasons why polling stops making progress, and each needs a different approach:

If the logic throws a `Throwable` other than an `Exception`, for instance an `Error`, the catch does not match, and execution will leave the for-loop, and likely reach the thread's `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, the default implementation of which logs the exception to `System.err` and terminates the thread. To prevent this, you should catch `Throwable` rather than `Exception`.

The second possibility is that some step in your logic doesn't terminate, for instance due to an infinite loop, a deadlock, waiting for I/O operations, or whatever. In this case, you'll want to take a thread dump to see where the thread is stuck. You can automate this as follows:

```
class Watchdog {
    final Duration gracePeriod;
    final Thread watchedThread;
    volatile Instant lastProgress;

    public Watchdog(Duration gracePeriod) {
        this.gracePeriod = gracePeriod;
        watchedThread = Thread.currentThread();
        everythingIsFine();
        
        var t = new Thread(this::keepWatch);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }
    
    public void everythingIsFine() {
        lastProgress = Instant.now();
    }
    
    void keepWatch() {
        while (true) {
            var silence = Duration.between(lastProgress, Instant.now());
            if (silence.compareTo(gracePeriod) > 0) {
                System.err.println("Watchdog hasn't seen any progress for " + silence.toSeconds() + " seconds. The watched thread is currently at:");
                for (var element : watchedThread.getStackTrace()) {
                    System.err.println("\tat " + element);
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(gracePeriod);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

while you can use as follows:

```
public class Test {
    void step() throws Exception {
        System.in.read();
    }
    
    void job() {
        var snoopy = new Watchdog(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        for (;;) {
            try {
                step();
                snoopy.everythingIsFine();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.err.println(t);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Test().job();
    }
}
```

once the grace period elapses, the WatchDog will print something like:

```
Watchdog hasn't seen any progress for 2 seconds. The watched thread is currently at:
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:293)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:255)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.implRead(BufferedInputStream.java:289)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:276)
    at stackoverflow.Test.step(Test.java:48)
    at stackoverflow.Test.job(Test.java:55)
    at stackoverflow.Test.main(Test.java:65)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @meriton. I got several clues from this answer to proceed further.

I implemented it with Scheduler in springboot which runs every 50 seconds interval and check last timestamp that was updated by for-loop logic. 
If the last updated timestamp is high enough, I will raise an alert.